# HP pavilion DV4 cannot enable wifi

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, drivers

I am installing windows on a HP Pavilion DV4 (sn:FQ378PA#ABG) and on both windows 10 and windows 7 I am unable to get windows to recognize the media buttons at the top of the keyboard, one of which is the wifi button, leaving the laptop stuck with wifi and bluetooth disabled by the hardware switch. I have already installed the drivers that HP has listed for the laptop, on both windows 10 and windows 7. The BIOS updater that HP provides does not work either, it says that the laptop is not compatible, even though it is the one provided. The laptop has a windows vista sticker on it, but I do not have access to a copy of that. Ideally I would like to get the whole media bar working, but I only need the wifi to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Go to Device Manager, is there anything under "Other Devices?"

Comment: There are 3 items called "Base System Device", windows could not automatically find drivers for them.